# VB.Net, Utilizing Excel assemblies, Memory leak

Tags: vb.net, excel, memory-leaks, vba

My program is essentially a form that uses the excel assemblies to open a file and puts the information into array lists.

After running my program multiple iterations I have found that in task manager I have multiple excel files still open, although they are hidden from my task bar. Additionally "System and compressed memory" takes up more space each time.

I assume that I did not properly release memory but I am not sure how, I currently have:

```
shXL = Nothing
wbXl = Nothing
appXL.Quit()
appXL = Nothing
```

Note: shxl is the worksheet, wbxl is the workbook, and appxl is the application.

Any help Would be appreciated

Comment: [There are a lot of response to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=close+excel+interop). I would suggest you look at an other library. I often had trouble with the interopt and it's very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some fully working open and close code

```
Private _xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Private _xlWSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Private _xlWBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

Private Sub btnOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpen.Click
    Dim filename As String = "C:\Scratch\Test.xlsx"
    _xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    _xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    _xlWBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    'close the workbook and quit the app
    If _xlWBook IsNot Nothing Then _xlWBook.Close()
    If _xlApp IsNot Nothing Then _xlApp.Quit()
    'destroy the objects
    If _xlWSheet IsNot Nothing Then _xlWSheet = Nothing
    If _xlWBook IsNot Nothing Then _xlWBook = Nothing
    If _xlApp IsNot Nothing Then _xlApp = Nothing

    'Force garbage collection
    GC.Collect()
End Sub
```

Also note that if you are *not* setting: `_xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False` then when you close the workbook, if you have any unsaved changes, this will wait for a non existant user to click yes or no to a "Save Changes" dialog which will probably cause the objects to hang around

Comment: I have an issue, one of the excel inputs has multiple sheets, and wbxl.close() breaks the code.

Comment: *WorkBooks* by definition can have multiple *WorkSheets*, Calling `wbxl.Close` will attempt to close all of them

Comment: Edit: Actually I am not sure is it is because of the multiple sheets, wbxl.close seems to work in one form but not the other where I check for multiple sheets. 

I removed wbxl.close and everything else seems to be fine

Comment: So I suppose the reason for the hang is that wbxl.close is having an issue closing all the sheets? Is there a different syntax that should be used in this case?

Comment: Please see the edit which now includes everything you need

Comment: Thank you, that explains the hang.

Comment: Haha, I did but  votes are not visible for people with under 15 rep